# UI Semantic dropdown component installation

Tags: semantic-ui, bulma

I would love to use the ui dropdown component in my website as css framework bulma does not have one

I pulled the package in through npm, selected the button module that has the dropdown component, ran gulp build and generated the .js and .css files

But if I try to access these files I get

```
mysite.dev/semantic/dist/components/dropdown.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Where am I going wrong?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the files are really in the right location? In our project with a Semantic UI build from scratch via gulp (see [here](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#install-gulp)) they're where you would expect them:

```
$ ll semantic/dist/components/d*
[...]
-rwxrwxr-x 1 yv yv  33634 Sep 30 14:41 semantic/dist/components/dropdown.css*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yv yv 133553 Sep 30 14:41 semantic/dist/components/dropdown.js
-rwxrwxr-x 1 yv yv  23689 Sep 30 14:41 semantic/dist/components/dropdown.min.css*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yv yv  48256 Sep 30 14:41 semantic/dist/components/dropdown.min.js
```

You can also install the dropdown module separately using an NPM command: `npm install semantic-ui-dropdown`, see [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html).